# order a child model with respect to parent model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have `Problem` and `Solution` model defined in my `models.py`. `Solution` has a foreignkey to the `Problem` model. That is, a problem can have many solutions.

I want to create urls like `www.example.com/problem/problem_id/solution/solution_number/` where `problem_id` describes the primary key of Problem model and `solution_number` describes the order in which the solution was posted for a particular problem. In other words, if a solution is first solution to a given problem, its order should be 1 and second solution to the same problem gets an order 2.

This will allow me to access a solution to particular problem like `Solution.objects.get(problem=problem, order=order)`

Answer (score 0):

easy

root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^problem/', include('your.apps.problem.urls')
]
```

problem.urls.py

```
from .views import solution

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<prob_id>\d+)/solution/(?P<sol_id>\d+)/$', solution)
]
```

views.py

```
def solution(request, prob_id, sol_id):
    sol = Solution.objects.get(problem_id=prob_id, pk=sol_id)
```

dont query by object in Foreignkey fields, better with `_id` which does not involve `Problem` table in this case.

you dont need `order`. ID is always asc ordered.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I have implemented a similar solution using CBV but this is what I don't want.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I have implemented a similar solution using CBV but this is what I don't want. Suppose there are two problems A and B. First problem A has three solutions and second has 4. Suppose the all the solutions to first problem were written followed by all the solutions to second problem. The ids of solutions to problem A will be [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6, 7] for solutions to problem B.

Comment: Current arrangement lets me make urls like /problem/1/solution/1 , /problem/1/solution/2/, However for second problem urls like /problem/2/solution/1 will not work since solution with id=1 does not belong to problem with id=2.

Comment: I want the url /problem/2/solution/1/ to return the first solution (order=1) to the problem with id=2.

Comment: @InQuilabi you dont build urls manually, if you build them using objects in your context, you will never get a wrong url/object.